# How do linux distros generally handle multilingual UI fonts?

Tags: fonts, user-interface

My question is specifically about whether there is a possibility to use different UI fonts for different languages. i.e. Ubuntu for English, Natsume Moji for Japanese, Noto Naksh for Arabic, etc..

And if possible, what is the tool for the job?